# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} n}{n^2+1}$ related to any popular constants

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7Binf%7D%20((-1)%5E(n-1)%20n%2F(n%5E2%2B1)))
shows this to be converging to roughly 0.2696:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} n}{n^2+1}$$

Is this related to other known constants?

Comment: It is indeed a convergent sequence. Why would you expect that it is related to any known constant?

Comment: I doubt it. Mathematica expresses this sum in terms of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: @Jack Sometimes WA gives longer expressions for something simple because of the way the query is framed. I just wanted to rule out that.

Comment: Its pretty close to the the formula for $\pi/4$, aka the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: Note $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} (2n-1)}{(2n-1)^2+1} = \frac12 \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} (2n-1)}{(2n-1)^2+1}$ can be expressed in term of trigonometric functions

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the Euler Macheroni constant $\gamma $ were to make an appearance here.

Comment: @user1952009 Could you elaborate?  I can't see it coming through in terms of trigonometric functions, hyperbolic or not.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson $\pi/4$ is almost triple the given series.  And the alternating harmonic series converges to $\ln(2)$.

Comment: oops you are right.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  $\frac{1}{e^{2i \pi z}-1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z-n}$ and $2\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} (2n-1)}{(2n-1)^2+1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^{n}  (\frac{1}{2n-1+i}+\frac{1}{2n-1-i})$

Comment: On a related note, we have the [FoxTrot series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoxTrotSeries.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose I can't let everyone post answers with no explanations now can I?

First, apply PFD to get

$$\frac n{n^2+1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{n+i}+\frac1{n-i}\right)$$

Thus, the given sum is equivalent to

$$S=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+i}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n-i}\right)$$

It is then straightforward to note that:

$$\Phi(z,s,\nu)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(n+\nu)^s}$$

Where $\Phi$ is the [Lerch Transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).  Thus, one form of your sum is

$$S=-\frac{\Phi(-1,1,i)+\Phi(-1,1,-i)}2$$

Another form follows from the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html).  To see this one, we split the sum over multiple parts:

$$2S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2n+i-1}-\frac1{2n+i}+\frac1{2n-i-1}-\frac1{2n-i}\right)$$

$$4S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n+\frac{i-1}2}-\frac1{n+\frac i2}+\frac1{n-\frac{i+1}2}-\frac1{n-\frac i2}\right)$$

Now we exploit the [series expansion of the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula):

$$\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+z}\right)$$

Thus, we obtain Mathematica's result:

$$4S=\psi\left(1+\frac i2\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)+\psi\left(1-\frac i2\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1-i}2\right)$$

By exploiting the recurrence formula

$$\psi(z+1)=\psi(z)+\frac1z$$

and the reflection formula

$$\psi(1-z)-\psi(z)=\pi\cot(\pi z)$$

We find that, equivalent to [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2342396/272831)'s answer,

$$4S=2i+2\psi\left(1+\frac i2\right)-\pi i\coth\left(\frac\pi2\right)-2\psi\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)+\pi i\tanh\left(\frac\pi2\right)$$

Since we know the sum is real,

$$S=\frac12\Re\left[\psi\left(1+\frac i2\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

It is the real part of 
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\Psi\left(\frac{i}2\right) -\Psi\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right) = \Psi\left(\frac{i}2\right) - \Psi(i) + \ln(2)$$

It could also be written as
$$ - \frac{\Phi(-1,1,1-i)+\Phi(-1,1,1+i)}{2}$$
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mathematica it is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{4} \left(-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right),
$$
where $\psi$ denotes the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

Numerically it is equal to 0.26961050270800898180..., which does not apear in the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index) , so it is not likely to be some 'known' number.